# Mounted ConfigMap volume is not served entirely

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, configmap

ASP.NET Core SPA with external config in wwwroot/config/config.json

Contents of config.json:

```
{
  "termsAndConditionsLink": "https://some-dev-url.with/legal/terms/"
}
```

When the file is **not being overwritten by a ConfigMap**, it works fine and I am able to get the full content of file.

```
curl https://dev-app.com/config/config.json
{
  "termsAndConditionsLink": "https://some-dev-url.with/legal/terms/"
}
```

When ConfigMap data is mounted to this path with Volume, it is not returned entirely.

```
curl https://dev-app.com/config/config.json
{
  "termsAndCon
```

The file is present in pod:

```
pwd
/app/wwwroot/config

ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Nov 20 08:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov 20 08:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 20 08:48 ..2018_11_20_08_48_02.390652870
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Nov 20 08:48 ..data ->         ..2018_11_20_08_48_02.390652870
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Nov 20 08:48 config.json -> ..data/config.json

cat config.json
{
  "termsAndConditionsLink": "https://some-dev-url.with/legal/terms/"
}
```

**ConfigMap.yaml**

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-config
data:
  config.json: |-
    {
      "termsAndConditionsLink": "https://some-dev-url.with/legal/terms/"
    }
```

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    ...
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        ...
    spec:
      containers:
        ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-volume
              mountPath: /app/wwwroot/config
      volumes:
        - name: my-volume
          configMap:
            name: my-config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that any other files in the `/app/wwwroot/config` directory are gone when mounting a volume at that location from the ConfigMap?

Have you tried [projected](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#projected) volume:

```
volumes:
  - name: my-volume
    projected:
      sources:
      - configMap:
          name: my-config
```

**EDIT:** For those that may come across such problem and don't read through the messages below the posts - after exchanging messages with @edbighead, another suggestion was to use `subPath` in the Deployment to leave the config directory writeable as ConfigMap volume mounts are read-only:

```
mountPath: /app/wwwroot/config/config.json 
subPath: config.json
```

That apparently *solved the problem*.

Comment: There's only one file in this directory, the original `/app/wwwroot/config/config.json`, and when it's overwritten by configmap (to use the same image but different configs on different environments), it's not served entirely by kestrel, but only first 15 chars.

Comment: @edbighead - I apparently didn't read thoroughly the whole question and you've provided good level of details. It is a strange behavior. Notice it is probably 16 characters, counting a new line character. Maybe it is just in the question but the ConfigMap's content is the same as in the original config.json. What do you see when the ConfigMap is something totally different? Also, it may be worth trying to use in the Deployment `mountPath: /app/wwwroot/config/config.json` and add `subPath: config.json` - this will leave the `config` directory writeable as ConfigMap volume mounts are read-only.

Comment: Thanks, specifying subpath resolved the problem. This is still very strange behavior though.